# Why does pandas NaT support date() method but not time() method?

Tags: pandas, datetime

I can't seem to comprehend the following behavior, why does one method break and the other doesn't?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                     

In [2]: pd.NaT                                                                  
Out[2]: NaT

In [3]: pd.NaT.date()                                                           
Out[3]: NaT

In [4]: pd.NaT.time()                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-19f140eaf187> in <module>
----> 1 pd.NaT.time()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/nattype.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype._make_error_func.f()

ValueError: NaTType does not support time

In [5]:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed in the Pandas project before.

See, for example, [this comment in PR #10372](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/10372#issuecomment-120741361), which implements the code that makes `date()` return `NaT` rather than raise an error:

> > I think things that have date should be NaT eg
> >     date,now,today
>
> Agreed. NaT is a datetime instance and also a date instance.
>
> > I am ok with time be Nat as well -even though it pushes the semantic boundaries
>
> I disagree. NaT is not a time instance. We should not return it from a method which promises to return a time.

So it boils down to `NaT`'s type implementing the same interfaces as Python's [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) and [date](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) types, but not the [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects) type.

This is natural, since Pandas timestamps can represent a full timestamp (with date and time) or a date, but not a time independent of a date.

For that reason, the few functions that convert or return objects of those two types will return `NaT`, while most others will raise an error.